# Why does the horizontal scrollbar reset its position when I update the ItemsSource of the DataGrid?

Tags: c#, wpf, scroll, datagrid, scrollbar

I have a small WPF application with a `DataGrid`. When I update my `dataSource` like this:

```
DataTable myTable = GetNewTableWithChangedRows();
MyGrid.ItemsSource = myTable.DefaultView;
```

The vertical scroll bar stays on the user defined position, but the horizontal scrollbar resets its position to zero.

Where is the difference? And how can I make the horizontal scrollbar stay on the user defined position?

Comment: Because you're totally emptying the DataGrid and replacing everything in it.

Comment: But why vertical scroll bar is stay on user defined position?

Comment: That's actually a good question.

Answer (score 2):

This occurs, because the `DataGrid` generates all columns anew on changing the items source. The column widths will be calculated again, so the scroll viewer will reset its horizontal position.

The vertical position (and the row selection) will be maintained by design: the `Selector` will try to maintain the current selection.

If you want to keep the horizontal scroll position unchanged, you have to prevent the automatic column generation. That means, you have to define the `DataGrid` columns manually:

```
<DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Header 1" Binding="{Binding Column1Value}"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Header 2" Binding="{Binding Column2Value}"/>
        <!-- ...and so on, for each column you need -->
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```